# Rails first app browser error. undefined local variable or method `state' for ActiveSupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Nwbie here. After following some guides to install and setup Ruby on Rails I have the following error when opening the server in the browser.

Guides:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmyvWz5TUWg&t=1567s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org
2. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Im using these versions

1. Ubuntu: 20.04.03 LTS
2. Ruby: 3.0.3
3. Rails: 7.0.2.1
4. SQLite3: 3.31.1
5. Node: 16.13.2
6. Yarn 1.22.17

> Puma caught this error: undefined local variable or method `state' for ActiveSupport::IsolatedExecutionState:Module (NameError) /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.1/lib/active_support/isolated_execution_state.rb:45:in` delete'
> /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:69:in `run!' /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in` call'
> /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call' /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in` call'
> /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/actionpack-7.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call' /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in` call'
> /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call' /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.1/lib/puma/request.rb:77:in` block in handle_request'
> /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown' /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.1/lib/puma/request.rb:76:in` handle_request'
> /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.1/lib/puma/server.rb:441:in `process_client' /home/matias/.rbenv/versions/3.0.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/puma-5.6.1/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in` block in spawn_thread'

I have no clue whats going on, also couldnt find any related topic here. Tried to re-install everything and with different versions, same error

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Initiating the server swith sudo showed some problems with Ruby version.

Check how you install ruby, make sure you have a clean installation. I recommend deleting everything and clean start with rbenv.

This guide made the thing:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FfXd0XQ4QbY&list=FL1o8s2zTqBUnUqNxwtF8fHA&index=1&t=90s&ab_channel=apiske